# Reading parameter from file and creating filenames

Tags: c

I want to read a name from a file (for example config_file.txt with only one entry like run)
and then create filenames with that, like run0.txt, run1.txt and so on.
But I get something like run..0.txt with two black dots.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXCHAR 1000

void generate(char const *fileName);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    generate("config_file.txt");
}

void generate(char const *fileName) {

    char id[MAXCHAR]; 
    FILE *fp;
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file %s", fileName);
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL) {
            strcpy(id, str);          
    }

    fclose(fp);

    FILE *filePtr;
    char filename[100];
    for(int i = 0;i < 8;i++){
        sprintf(filename, "%s%d.txt", id,i);
        filePtr = fopen(filename, "w");
    }
    fclose(filePtr); 
}
```

Comment: You've not zapped the newline that `fgets()` keeps in the string returned after it reads a line.  Your `fclose(filePtr)` call should be inside the `for` loop, too.

Comment: ah, that is it, can you give me an idea how to fix that?

Comment: did you just check your input file? make sure it doesn't have `run.` I've run your code, it's working as expected

Comment: The reliable way of zapping the newline is `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';` — alternatives have to worry about empty lines and no newline and so on, but that works regardless.  You can use `"\n\r"` if you think you might need to deal with CRLF line endings, but that's normally handled for you by `fopen()` not using `b` in the open mode.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem.

Comment: `printf("Could not open file %s", fileName);` is not quite the canonical example of a useless error message, but this is much better written as `perror(fileName)`.  Make sure you call it immediately after `fopen` so that `errno` is not modified by any intervening calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, your code does not zap the newline that `fgets()` normally preserves as it reads lines before trying to add the extension to it.

The simple and reliable method for zapping the newline is:

```
str[stcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
```

There are alternatives that might be more efficient (though efficiency is probably a red herring here — creating files takes a lot longer than reading through a short line of characters), but you have to get a variety of conditions right (empty buffer, buffer with no newline, etc).

You also have:

```
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Could not open file %s", fileName);
    return 1;
}
```

1. You should report errors on `stderr` instead of `stdout`.
2. You might consider including the error number and/or error message.
3. You should finish the message with a newline.
4. You can't write `return 1;` in a function returning `void` — the compiler must complain about that.

C11 [§6.8.6.4 The `return` statement](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.4):

> ¶1 A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is `void`. A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is `void`.

Hence, you should consider writing:

```
if (fp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s for reading: %s\n", fileName, strerror(errno));
    return;
}
```

I normally use a set of error reporting functions that I wrote, one of which tells the library the name of the program (`err_setarg0(argv[0]);` in `main()`) and the others of which produce error messages as desired. This code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

I'd write:

```
if (fp == NULL)
    err_syserr("failed to open file '%s' for reading: ", fileName);
```

The function doesn't return.  If I wanted to return, I'd use `err_sysrem()` ('remark') and arrange a return.  The `sys` part of the name means that the error number and message are automatically reported too.  I prefer these to `perror()` because `perror()` doesn't make it easy to get the program name etc into the error message.

There are analogous libraries available on some systems — `err(3)` on macOS, and also available on Linux ([`err(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html), does roughly the same job.