# Sleep instruction doesn't work with signal handler

Tags: c, linux, signals, sleep

```
void handler ( int sig, siginfo_t * info, void * se)
{

}

int setup_sig(){
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if(-1 == sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa , NULL)){return 0;} return 1;
}

void main()
{
    printf("before\n");
    setup_sig();
    sleep(3);
    printf("after\n");
}
```

This code needs to register to signal `SIGCHLD` and then sleep 3 seconds, and then go out.

This code skip on sleep instruction, why?

Comment: Properly formatted and indented code is easier to read and understand than what you have here.

Comment: So it doesn't wait 3 seconds?

Comment: The compiler should reject `setup_sig()`; you cannot return a value from a function that has `void` as the return type (see also [Reading parameter from file and creating filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60196698/15168), which quotes the relevant part of the standard).  Separately [What should `main()` return in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721336/15168) — the answer is not `void` except, perhaps, on Windows.

Comment: May we have [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with complete headers, complier flags, no compilation warnings, and also a detailed description of the behavior you expect versus the behavior you observe?  Like @user253751, I don't quite know what you mean by sleep "doesn't work" or that the code "skip on sleep instruction."

Answer (score 2):

The [Linux documentation for `sleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) lists the following attributes at the bottom:

```
┌──────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────────────┐
│Interface │ Attribute     │ Value                       │
├──────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│sleep()   │ Thread safety │ MT-Unsafe sig:SIGCHLD/linux │
└──────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```

That `sig:SIGCHLD/linux` is important in this context. As per [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/attributes.7.html), it's explained as follows (my emphasis):

> `sig`: Functions marked with sig as a MT-Safety issue may temporarily install a signal handler for internal purposes, which may interfere with other uses of the signal, identified after a colon.
>
> This safety problem can be worked around by ensuring that no other uses of the signal will take place for the duration of the call. Holding a non-recursive mutex while calling all functions that use the same temporary signal; ***blocking that signal before the call and resetting its handler afterwards is recommended.***

Blocking a signal can be done with the `sigprocmask` call, such as with:

```
// Need signal.h for this stuff.

sigset_t mask;

if ((sigemptyset(&mask) == -1) || (sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD) == -1)) {
    // handle failure here.
}

if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1) {
    // handle failure here.
}

sleep(3);

// Probably need to re-establish CHLD signal handler as well as unmasking.

if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1) {
    // handle failure here.
}
```

Comment: So how can I implement that ?

Comment: @paramikoooo, I thought the bolded text made that clear, I'll elaborate.